# How to calculate the speed of a collapse?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Let's suppose i'm using dominoes or card pyramids or any other structure. 
How could I calculate the maximum speed of a pancake collapse? How close to free fall could it get? What variables should be taken into consideration?

Comment: For dominos the most important variable is the spacing because that determines the angle at which it contacts its nearest neighbor.  Once that is set you need to determine the equation of motion for the angular movement, not a trivial exercise since the torque increases as the angle increases.  Solve this EOM and then determine the time required to reach the contact angle. Multiply this time by the number of dominoes in the chain and you have an approximate answer.